# How to reflect entity field changes in its methods automatically?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Say this is my entity class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TodoRepository::class)
 */
class Todo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
     */
    private $username;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I want to change the field username to name. I am able to do so using the doctrine:schema:update --force function in CLI. The change is reflected in the database. However, how do I reflect that change in field name in the entity class methods? I know I can manually do so but it is tedious.

Any way to do so dynamically? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Maybe I dont't understand your question right, but why can't you use your search and replace functionality of your IDE?

Comment: Oh hell, I could. I was just wondering if there was a function in doctrine that updates the Entity class to reflect th field changes. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, I did not think about it.

Comment: I think there is no function like that, because it also has to update the names specified in your Form-Types, Twig-Templates or config files. A software that covers all these different places does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these tools:

- [symfony/maker-bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html) (to generate new fields on your entity)
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (to create script dynamically)
- [doctrine:mapping:import](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) to generate entities from an existing database.

But if you want to alter a entity that you already use a lot in your project, you should use a smart editor. I do it via [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). Renaming the `name` property will not only update the entity, but the whole code of your project. Each time `$user->getUsername()` occurs, it will be updated to `$user->getName()`

> The Rename and Move refactorings work for files, functions, constants, classes, properties, methods, parameters, and local and global variables. Make global project changes easily and safely. Local changes are made instantly in-place.

> The following refactorings are also available: Extract Variable / Constant / Field / Method / Interface, Inline variable, Push members Up / Pull members Down, Change signature, Move class to another namespace, Move static member, Make Static refactoring.